# Complement of a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

What are the conditions for the complement of a connected graph to be connected?

In particular, when is the complement of a connected regular graph connected? I feel that if the regularity of graph is $\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil$, its complement should be connected, though it's mere intuition.

Comment: Do you think that such conditions exist? Please: be more specific with your question. There could exist too many possible good answers, but maybe you have something precise in your mind.

Comment: @ Crostul, edited!

Comment: I think $K_{m,m}$ (for $m\ge 1$) is a counterexample to the particular conjecture you gave in the question; its complement is two disjoint copies of $K_m$, right?

Comment: (The extremality of that situation suggests a counting argument: if the graph is $k$-regular with $k < \lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil$, the complement will have too many edges to be disconnected.  I doubt this is an interesting enough condition for you, though.)

Comment: @Steven Taschuk, you are right. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Why "complement of a **connected** graph? The complement of a disconnected graph is always connected, so you are really asking, when is the complement of a graph connected? But every graph is the complement of another graph, so you might as well ask, "When is a graph connected?" Or "when is a regular graph connected?"

Answer (score 1):

"For every two partitions of the vertices on two groups there must be missing edge between groups."

$=> $ if there are $\ge 2$ connected components in the complement graph then we can group our vertices into two groups: {one connected component, the others}. For the initial graph there is no missing edge between them.

$<= $ if complement graph is connected, than for every partition there is an edge between groups. And this edge is missing for the same pertition in the initial graph.

Proved.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what the second paragraph concludes?

Comment: that the connectivity of the complement graph provides holding mentioned condition for the initial graph.

Comment: we assume complement to be disconnected with mentioned condition,but where is a contradiction to lead us to the connectivity of complement.

Comment: What does "two groups" mean please? What's the conclusion of your derivation?